# Radio Button Selection in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, view, visible, android-radiobutton

In my project I have two radio button under a radio group.By default the first radio button is selected.When first radio button is in selected state four checkboxes will be visible if second radio button is in selected state all four checkboxes will be gone to invisible state.I dont know how to implement this.Can anyone suggest me?

Thank you!!!

Comment: set the visibility of radio group to VIEW.GONE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its too simple. Earlier you mentioned that first time your first radio button is selected then at that time you have to just set visibility for checkboxes visible. Like

```
 ch1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // same for other checkboxes
```

And when you select second radio button at that time set visibility for that check boxes ***GONE***. Like

```
 ch1.setVisibility(View.GONE);   // same for other checkboxes
```

UPDATE:

```
 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(checkedId == R.id.urfirstR1)
          {
                ch1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

       else if(checkedId == R.id.ursecondr2)
          {
                ch1.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
          }
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah u are right.I want to it to happen when the radio button changes...Where i ll put this condition in Oncreate()?

Comment: yes it is on oncreate() oncheckedChangeListener of RadioGroup. CHeck my updated answer.

Comment: @Barbie ur wel come..!!

Answer (score 0):

take this reference and do your work under this condition 
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

take all check box under one layout and invisible or visible that layout according to this example

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

      if(checkedId == R.id.firstradiobutton)
               {
                 // visible all checkbox here
              }

       else if(checkedId == R.id.secondradiobutton)
              {
                  // invisible all checkbox here
              }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution.

By default you don't have to do anything. and onCheckchangelistener use below code.

```
radiobutton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            ch1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
           ch2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
          ch3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
        ch4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
        }
    });
```

Put this inside your onCreate method. and replace ID name of checkboxes and radio button's as per your ID names.